# Exibir dia da semana, conforme data utilizada na consulta PHP

Tags: php, datetime, data, timestamp

Boa tarde a todos, estou com uma dúvida em um projeto do curso. Tenho um formulário aonde eu busco pacientes agendados em um determinado dia do mês.

Quando eu realizar a consulta para apresentar os pacientes agendados, preciso apresentar também qual seria o dia da semana, desse dia do mês utilizado no select. O formato da data está no padrão "dia/mês/ano".

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Para exibir o dia da semana você pode utilizar o D quando for formatar a data. `echo date("D", strtotime("20/12/2017"));` http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: O exemplo que você me enviou funcionou em parte, preciso que seja dinâmico. Eu recebo a data que será utilizada na consulta na seguinte variável "$p_data" com base nessa data eu preciso exibir o dia da semana.

Comment: É só você passar a variável para a função `strtotime($variable)`

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo a solução!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte função do PHP:

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp ] );
```

Ficando da seguinte forma:

```
echo date("D", strtotime("20/12/2017"));
```

Existe outros formatos como:

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
```

Referências: [Função date()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php), [função strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php).